# Can I pause my free tier service on AWS and resume it whenever is required?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, hosting, web-hosting

I've been using AWS free tier service for hosting my blogging site. For some reasons, I didn't get time to post some articles or blogs on my site and my site is almost as it is as I hosted it. And I am paying each month $0.5 as AWS Bill.

I just wanna know that is it possible to stop  my free tier service for now and can continue this  service afterward when I'll be in need of hosting it again. And if it is possible How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS does not include functionality to pause the free tier, although it's important to understand there are 3 types of free tier:

- 12 months free - These free tiers start from the moment you open the account, they will last 12 months from when you created the account after which you will be charged.
- Free forever - Some services offer free usage of a service up to a certain service limit, an example of this would be Lambda which supports 1,000,000 invocations a month.
- Free trial - Some services offer a limited trial from the moment you start using them.

For more information on which services are covered under these categories, take a look at the [Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) page in the AWS documentation.

Comment: I am using 12 month free tier service. Does this mean that if i want to stop paying for free tier service now I have to stop my hosting at AWS

Comment: This will end up finishing 12 months from when you created the account unfortunately :(